# CreateProcess , WaitForSingleObject , Disable Input on Calling Application

Tags: delphi, createprocess, disabled-input

I'm calling another Program which only displays a webpage like this :

Problem : if I Create a Process with the Button , and while the Created Process is open , I click on a Checkbox on the calling form , I close the created process the Checkbox is checked .

I tried to use the DisableTaskWindows(0) as seen in the .ShowModal function . But it does not work as I expected. While it does disable the form . But after I enable it , it seems like the form processes the click event anyway. Kinda like if it has a message queue or something .

Can anyone tell me what is it that I am doing wrong here?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  StartupInfo : TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInfo : TProcessInformation;
  ProcessCreated : Boolean;
  CommandLine : string;
  WindowList: TTaskWindowList;
begin
  WindowList := DisableTaskWindows(0);
  CommandLine:='webmodule.exe';
  uniqueString(CommandLine);
  ZeroMemory(@StartupInfo, SizeOf(StartupInfo));
  StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(StartupInfo);
  ProcessCreated := CreateProcess(PChar(nil), PChar(CommandLine), nil, nil, false, 0, nil, nil, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo);
  if ProcessCreated then
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE)
  else
    ShowMessage('Error : could not execute!');
  CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
  EnableTaskWindows(WindowList);
end;
```

**UPDATE**

unfortunately I am not sure how one uses the RegisterWaitForSingleObject function ... I tried this , but is not working . I am missing the CallBack maybe ? But I have no idea how to use it.

```
  if ProcessCreated then
  begin
//    WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    while (RegisterWaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess,ProcessInfo.hProcess,nil,nil,INFINITE,0) = false) do
    begin
      Form1.Color:=RGB(random(255),random(255),random(255));
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;

    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('Error : could not execute!');
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

I think I might have solved it , I removed the Enable Disable for the Form . Instead I do this after I executed the Process .

```
  while PeekMessage(Msg, 0, WM_KEYFIRST, WM_KEYLAST, PM_REMOVE or PM_NOYIELD) do;
  while PeekMessage(Msg, 0, WM_MOUSEFIRST, WM_MOUSELAST, PM_REMOVE or PM_NOYIELD) do;
```

Comment: Have you tried simply setting the calling Form's `Enabled` property instead of using `(Disable|Enable)TaskWindows()`? I would even go as far as suggest using [`RegisterWaitForSingleObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerwaitforsingleobject) or equivalent to allow the code to return control to the main message loop while waiting on the spawned process, and then let the wait callback function close the opened handles and re-enable the Form

Comment: Only call CloseHande if CreateProcess succeeds

Comment: unfortunately Form1.Enabled:=false and Form1.Enabled:=true does not work. After I enable the Form ... the CheckBox is clicked ...

Comment: The point about using `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` was to change your code to run **asynchronously**. If `CreateProcess` succeeds, call `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` *once* and then exit from `Button1Click` immediately. *In the background*, the OS will continue waiting on the spawned process, and when it ends then you are notified via callback. This way, you can let the main message loop continue to run normally, and it will swallow user input while the Form is disabled, until the process ends and the Form is re-enabled. DON'T try to do everything inside of `Button1Click`.

Comment: The problem is WaitForSingleObject is blocking the main thread and so it can't process (input) messages. The disabled form should "beep" for instance when clicked. Remy's suggestion would work, or MsgWaitForMultipleObjects..

Comment: @Remy : i am afraid that i don’t fully understand how this callback works . How do I do this after Createprocess  Success ? And then where do I wait for the callback ?

Comment: @user1937012 you give `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` a pointer to a function, the OS calls that function when the requested handle is signaled (when the spawned process ends). You don't wait on the callback, you move on and let the function be called at some later time.

Comment: @user1937012 I added an answer with examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are blocking your app's main message loop while waiting for the spawned process to exit, so you are not allowing your app to process user input until after that process ends.  You need to let your app process messages normally, don't block them. If you disable your Form while the spawned process is running, user input will automatically be discarded for you.

Try something more like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  StartupInfo : TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInfo : TProcessInformation;
  CommandLine : string;
begin
  CommandLine := 'webmodule.exe';
  UniqueString(CommandLine);
  ZeroMemory(@StartupInfo, SizeOf(StartupInfo));
  StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(StartupInfo);
  if not CreateProcess(PChar(nil), PChar(CommandLine), nil, nil, FALSE, 0, nil, nil, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Error : could not execute!');
    Exit;
  end;
  CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
  Enabled := False;
  repeat
    case MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, ProcessInfo.hProcess, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT) of
      WAIT_OBJECT_0: Break;
      WAIT_OBJECT_0+1: Application.ProcessMessages;
    else
      begin
        ShowMessage('Error : could not wait!');
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  until False;
  CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
  Enabled := True;
end;
```

Or this:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(ToFrm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    ...
  private
    hWaitObj, hWaitProcess: THandle;
    procedure WaitFinished;
    ...
  end;

... 

procedure WaitCallback(lpParameter: Pointer; WaitFired: Boolean); stdcall;
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil, TForm1(lpParameter).WaitFinished);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  StartupInfo : TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInfo : TProcessInformation;
  CommandLine : string;
begin
  CommandLine := 'webmodule.exe';
  UniqueString(CommandLine);
  ZeroMemory(@StartupInfo, SizeOf(StartupInfo));
  StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(StartupInfo);
  if not CreateProcess(PChar(nil), PChar(CommandLine), nil, nil, FALSE, 0, nil, nil, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Error : could not execute!');
    Exit;
  end;
  CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
  if not RegisterWaitForSingleObject(hWaitObj, ProcessInfo.hProcess, WaitCallback, Self, INFINITE, WT_EXECUTELONGFUNCTION or WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE) then
  begin
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
    ShowMessage('Error : could not wait!');
    Exit;
  end;
  hWaitProcess := ProcessInfo.hProcess;
  Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.WaitFinished;
begin
  UnregisterWait(hWaitObj);
  CloseHandle(hWaitProcess);
  Enabled := True;
end;
```

Comment: The callback runs in a different thread? Is that the reason you queue it to the main thread?

Comment: Yes. [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerwaitforsingleobject): "***The callback routine is executed by a worker thread** when the object's state becomes signaled or the time-out interval elapses. When the wait is completed, you must call the `UnregisterWait` or `UnregisterWaitEx` function to cancel the wait operation... **Do not make a blocking call to either of these functions from within the callback function**.*"

Comment: @Remy : this is awesome!!! thank you!!! I will study the code and read the documentation again.

Comment: @Remy : I am reading the MSDN Docs for the MsgWaitForMultipleObjects , so far I managed to grasp everything . There is only one thing which eludes me . pHandles . It says an Array of Object Handles . Yet when I check the MSDN Docs for the CreateProcess , and then the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure it says Handle to Newly created object . (not array of Object Handles ) . And if I am not totaly confused here , the MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, ProcessInfo.hProcess, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT ) in the code receives only one Handle . It works , I am just trying to understand how it works .

Comment: @user1937012 `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` does take an array of handles. It is perfectly valid to pass it an array of 1 handle. In Delphi, that parameter is declared as an untyped `var`, so it is possible to skip creating an actual array when passing only 1 handle. The memory address of a single variable, and the memory address of an array of 1 element, are equivalent.

Comment: @Remy : your second example did not work at first , I did not really understand why . So I basically poked at it . Until I finally found that the problem was `@hWaitObj` , I needed to change it to hWaitObj . After that it works as expected . Why it worked, unfortunately no idea :(

Comment: @Remy : I modified the code even further , and it still works , is this also valid ? `procedure WaitCallBack(lpParameter: Pointer; WaitFired: Boolean); stdcall;` and I altered the **RegisterWaitForSingleObject** like this   `if not RegisterWaitForSingleObject(hWaitObj, ProcessInfo.hProcess, WaitCallback, Self, Infinite,WT_EXECUTELONGFUNCTION or WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE) then`

Comment: @user1937012 my computer died earlier this week and I lost access to my Delphi, so I couldn't check the actual declarations when I wrote that example, so I guessed. I must have guessed wrong. If your tweaks work, then so be it. I have updated my example.